# adding significance levels under regression result table

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I have a table as the following:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
\caption{Dependent Variable: Enrollment}
\begin{tabular}{c c c c}
\hline\hline 
\textbf{Variable} & \textbf{Model 1} & \textbf{Model 2} & \textbf{Model 3}\\ \hline
frl         &      -0.012   &      -0.052   &      -0.156** \\
            &      (0.04)   &      (0.06)   &      (0.06)   \\
minority    &               &       0.034   &       0.097*  \\
            &               &      (0.05)   &      (0.04)   \\
disting     &               &               &       0.439***\\
            &               &               &      (0.06)   \\
cons       &       0.529***&       0.530***&       0.518***\\
            &      (0.03)   &      (0.03)   &      (0.02)   \\
\hline  N           &     196   &     196   &     196   \\          
R$^{2}$           &       0.001   &       0.003   &       0.235   \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I would like to add the statistical significance stars bellow, but I can't seem to add code with three multicolumn. I tried adding the following at the end of the table but does not seem to work:

```
\bottomrule
\vspace{-3mm}\\
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\textsuperscript{***}$p<0.01$, 
  \textsuperscript{**}$p<0.05$, 
  \textsuperscript{*}$p<0.1$,
```

How could I add the textsuperscripts?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can, in fact, use a `\multicolumn` and `\addlinespace` from the `booktabs` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
\caption{Dependent Variable: Enrollment}
\begin{tabular}{c c c c}
\toprule
\textbf{Variable} & \textbf{Model 1} & \textbf{Model 2} & \textbf{Model 3}\\ 
\midrule
frl         &      -0.012   &      -0.052   &      -0.156** \\
            &      (0.04)   &      (0.06)   &      (0.06)   \\
minority    &               &       0.034   &       0.097*  \\
            &               &      (0.05)   &      (0.04)   \\
disting     &               &               &       0.439***\\
            &               &               &      (0.06)   \\
cons       &       0.529***&       0.530***&       0.518***\\
            &      (0.03)   &      (0.03)   &      (0.02)   \\
\midrule
 N           &     196   &     196   &     196   \\          
R$^{2}$           &       0.001   &       0.003   &       0.235   \\
\bottomrule
\addlinespace[1ex]
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\textsuperscript{***}$p<0.01$, 
  \textsuperscript{**}$p<0.05$, 
  \textsuperscript{*}$p<0.1$}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Below there's another possibility using the [`ctable`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ctable) package; I used some boxes to heide the width of the superscripted characters:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\ctable[
  notespar,
  caption={Dependent Variable: Enrollment}
]{c c c c}
{\tnote[*]{$p<0.1$}\tnote[**]{$p<0.5$}\tnote[***]{$p<0.01$}}{
\toprule
\textbf{Variable} & \textbf{Model 1} & \textbf{Model 2} & \textbf{Model 3}\\ 
\midrule
frl         &      -0.012   &      -0.052   &      -0.156\tmark[{\makebox[0pt][l]{**}}] \\
            &      (0.04)   &      (0.06)   &      (0.06)   \\
minority    &               &       0.034   &       0.097\tmark[{\makebox[0pt][l]{*}}]  \\
            &               &      (0.05)   &      (0.04)   \\
disting     &               &               &       0.439\tmark[{\makebox[0pt][l]{***}}]\\
            &               &               &      (0.06)   \\
cons       &       0.529\tmark[{\makebox[0pt][l]{***}}]&       0.530\tmark[{\makebox[0pt][l]{***}}]&       0.518\tmark[{\makebox[0pt][l]{***}}]\\
            &      (0.03)   &      (0.03)   &      (0.02)   \\
\midrule  
N           &     196   &     196   &     196   \\          
R$^{2}$           &       0.001   &       0.003   &       0.235   \\
\bottomrule}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Without `booktabs` nor `ctable`, you can do something like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
\caption{Dependent Variable: Enrollment}
\begin{tabular}{c c c c}
\hline\hline
\textbf{Variable} & \textbf{Model 1} & \textbf{Model 2} & \textbf{Model 3}\\ 
\hline
frl         &      -0.012   &      -0.052   &      -0.156** \\
            &      (0.04)   &      (0.06)   &      (0.06)   \\
minority    &               &       0.034   &       0.097*  \\
            &               &      (0.05)   &      (0.04)   \\
disting     &               &               &       0.439***\\
            &               &               &      (0.06)   \\
cons       &       0.529***&       0.530***&       0.518***\\
            &      (0.03)   &      (0.03)   &      (0.02)   \\
\hline
 N           &     196   &     196   &     196   \\          
R$^{2}$           &       0.001   &       0.003   &       0.235   \\
\hline
\\[-1.75ex]
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\textsuperscript{***}$p<0.01$, 
  \textsuperscript{**}$p<0.05$, 
  \textsuperscript{*}$p<0.1$}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There's no problem adding the content at the bottom of the `tabular`, as long as `\multicolumn` is the first element in a cell:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Dependent Variable: Enrollment}
  \begin{tabular}{c r@{}l r@{}l r@{}l}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Variable} & 
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Model 1}} & 
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Model 2}} & 
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Model 3}} \\
    \midrule
    frl         &  $-$0&.012   &  $-$0&.052   &  $-$0&.156\textsuperscript{**}  \\
                &    (0&.04)   &    (0&.06)   &    (0&.06)    \\
    minority    &      &       &     0&.034   &     0&.097\textsuperscript{*}   \\
                &      &       &    (0&.05)   &    (0&.04)    \\
    disting     &      &       &      &       &     0&.439\textsuperscript{***} \\
                &      &       &      &       &    (0&.06)    \\
    cons        &     0&.529\textsuperscript{***}&     0&.530\textsuperscript{***}&     0&.518\textsuperscript{***} \\
                &    (0&.03)   &    (0&.03)   &    (0&.02)    \\
    \midrule
    N           &   196&       &   196&       &   196&        \\          
    R$^{2}$     &     0&.001   &     0&.003   &     0&.235    \\
  \bottomrule
  \multicolumn{3}{l}{\rule{0pt}{1.2\normalbaselineskip}% strut
    \textsuperscript{***}$p < 0.01$, 
    \textsuperscript{**}$p < 0.05$, 
    \textsuperscript{*}$p < 0.1$} 
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

For consistency, if you're using `\textsuperscript` to reference the components below the table, items should also use `\textsuperscript`. Moreover, it may be of interest to align the `tabular` content at the decimal point (as I've done above, using a poor-man's `D`-column).

Answer (score 2):

Given that the data columns contain numbers with decimals, it's very helpful to the reader if the numbers are aligned on the decimal markers. This may be achieved by using the `dcolumn` package and defining a suitable decimal-style column type. A side-benefit of using this approach is that the `-` symbols affixed to negative numbers will be typeset as proper mathematical "minus" symbols rather than as a short "dashes".

As has already been pointed out in the earlier answers, you (i) can place the legend about the standard errors and significance levels in rows at the bottom of the table by encasing the information in `\multicolumn{4}{l}{...}` statements, and (ii) may want to use the `booktabs` package and its commands `\toprule`, `\midrule`, etc instead to get well-spaced horizontal lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}{D{.}{.}{2.5}}           % alignment on decimal marker
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % shorthand macro
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Dependent Variable: Enrollment}
\begin{tabular}{l ddd}
\toprule
\textbf{Regressor}       & \mc{\textbf{Model 1}} 
&  \mc{\textbf{Model 2}} & \mc{\textbf{Model 3}} \\
\midrule
frl        & -0.012   & -0.052   &      -0.156^{**} \\
           & (0.04)   & (0.06)   &      (0.06)      \\
minority   &          &  0.034   &       0.097^{*}  \\
           &          & (0.05)   &      (0.04)      \\
disting    &          &          &       0.439^{***}\\
           &          &          &      (0.06)      \\
cons       &  0.529^{***}& 0.530^{***}&  0.518^{***}\\
           & (0.03)      &(0.03)      &  (0.02)     \\
\midrule
$N$        & \mc{196} & \mc{196} &    \mc{196}   \\
$R^{2}$    &  0.001   &  0.003   &       0.235   \\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{4}{l}{(Standard errors in parentheses)}\\
\multicolumn{4}{l}{$^{***}\ p<0.01$; $^{**}\ p<0.05$; $^{*}\ p<0.1$}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```