# how to draw a table for comparision

Tags: tables

i want to draw a table similar to this, but i have no idea about it, could someone can help me with it. I appreciate it!! [image]

Comment: Have you tried doing a quick Google search (choose images for quickly identifying tables)? "Table latex" already brings a lot of good results. There have been innumerable questions on tables, from various perspectives. Try modifying one for your needs and feel free to ask questions if you get stuck on something.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE by the way!

Comment: This table is not quite recommendable…

Comment: Which part of the table gives you difficulties? You can see [adding significance levels under regression result table](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/165241) for some inspiration.

Comment: Thanks for reply, a table of three columns for different three items' comparision. a little different table from what i showed is to combine the column (1) and (2) as one, and compare with the rest of two supports.

Comment: Thanks @Torbjørn T, that is a really nice example, but how can i divide each of column into  two sub-columns as two attributes

Comment: You're thinking in the wrong direction. What you want to do is make a single cell span two columns, which you can do with `\multicolumn`, as described in [How to merge columns in a table?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22861)

Answer (score 3):

Some pointers:

- Load the `booktabs` package and use the macros `\toprule`, `\midrule`, `\bottomrule`, and `\cmidrule` to generate well-spaced horizontal lines.
- Load the `dcolumn` package to align the numbers in the data columns on the decimal markers.
- Use `\multicolumn{.}{.}{.}` instructions to combine cells and/or change the column type for a given cell.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{table}{4} % just for this example

\begin{table}
\caption{Logistic regression estimates of support for rebel groups}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ @{} l *{4}{d{3.6}} @{} } % 1 "l" column, 4 "d" columns
\toprule
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Support I}  % combine 2 columns, use "c" column type
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{Support II} % change column type from "d" to "c"
& \multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{Support III} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-4} \cmidrule(l){5-5} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)} % change column type from "d" to "c"
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}
& \multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{(4)} \\
\midrule
Rebels much weaker & -0.408 && -0.524^{*} & -0.564^{*} \\
 & (0.305) & & (0.318) & (0.323) \\
\dots \\
\addlinespace
\emph{AIC} & 386.471 & 510.461 & 363.585 & 347.002\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the queries posted by the OP in the comments. I interpret your comments as wanting to have a header named "Support II" that spans columns 4 and 5 and wanting to get rid of the header named "Support III" placed over column 5.

If this interpretation is correct, you should (a) replace `\multicolumn{1}{c}{Support II}` with `\multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Support II}`, (b) omit `& \multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{Support III}`, and (c) replace `\cmidrule(lr){4-4} \cmidrule(l){5-5}` with `\cmidrule(l){4-5}`, i.e., replace the two single-column-width rules with a rule that spans columns 4 and 5.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{table}{4} % just for this example

\begin{table}
\caption{Logistic regression estimates of support for rebel groups}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ @{} l *{4}{d{3.6}} @{} }
\toprule
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Support I}
& \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Support II} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}
& \multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{(4)} \\
\midrule
Rebels much weaker & -0.408 && -0.524^{*} & -0.564^{*} \\
 & (0.305) & & (0.318) & (0.323) \\
\dots \\
\addlinespace
\emph{AIC} & 386.471 & 510.461 & 363.585 & 347.002\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping, but if i want to divide support 2 with multi-columns (3) and (4), and delete the column support 3, i tried to copy your support 1 design to instead of support 2, but it shows mistakes happened in "\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-4} \cmidrule(l){5-5} ", can you please tell me how to do it? Thanks

Comment: @Field.D - I'm afraid I didn't understand your comment. Could you rephrase it?

Comment: Sorry, what i mean is that i want to combine "support 2" and "support 3" as one column which is similar to "support 1".

Comment: this means "support 2" has two items which are (3) and (4), and "support 3" is deleted permanently

Comment: Thanks!!!  i did not understand "\cmidrule(lr)" before, but right now i fixed it. Thank you sooo much